# Writing a common event bearing same functionality for two identical controls with different names

Tags: .net, wpf, xaml, events

Suppose i have a XAML code that has two dialog boxes with textblocks. I have an event that's associated with the textblock on one of the dialog boxes. Can i re-use the same event in such a way for the other textblock on the other dialog box such that it handles both the elements? I dont want to create another event, copy-paste the code from the existing event and just rename the controls there or factor the common functionality into a function that accepts a textblock object.  This is how i dream of laying it out:

EDIT: included additional textblocks and added to the event comments

```
<XamDialogWindow> 
 <TextBlock Name="ctrl1" KeyUp="keyUp_event" />
 <TextBlock Name="ctrl2" />
 ...
</XamDialogWindow>

<XamDialogWindow> 
 <TextBlock Name="ctrl3" KeyUp="keyUp_event" />
 <TextBlock Name="ctrl4" />
 ...
</XamDialogWindow>

private void keyUp_event(object o, KeyEventArgs a){ //Just one event
  //copy from one control to the other
  //For eg, if event raised from ctrl1 then copy from ctrl1 to ctrl2
}
```

Is this possible?

Comment: I dont understand how i can use the two controls without if-else in the event.

Comment: why not? I can not see any reason for this.

Comment: Wont my `o` be different for every event invocation?

Comment: What if i have two textblocks on evey dialog box and i want to do copy value from one textblock to the other. How can i use the second textblock respectively?

Comment: That's a rather different problem which doesn't have much to do with shared event handlers.

Answer (score 1):

In XAML you don't need to name the controls at all.

so both controls will happily fire off the same handler

however you may find that having the event on the XamDialogWindow instead of the text box simplifies the matter for you as then you can check the event trail to find the source of the event and then refer to the XamDialogWindow's children to locate the other control

see     OriginalSource in 
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.input.keyeventargs.aspx

Comment: Side note: if you just want to copy the text then binding the second control to the first would be the better method however if you are just using that as an example then that doesn't apply here

Answer (score 0):

yeah you can directly call up the same event handler for two controls. No need of giving names to the controls also.

In the code behind if you need which control has fired the event you can do this like

```
String name=((TextBlock)sender).name;
if(name=="ctrl1")
    {// do something here}
else
    {//do some other here}
```